# How to replicate Excel's COUNTIF in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, excel-formula

How to write below Excel code in R?

```
COUNTIF($A$4:A4,A4)
```

I have > 100k rows of data where I want to fetch `COUNTIF($A$4:A4,A4) = 1` value. I am able to do it in Excel, however, I am facing issue in R

```
Date            Worker ID

10/31/2017     3152
9/30/2017      3152
8/31/2017      3152
7/31/2017      3152
6/30/2017      3152
5/31/2017      3152
4/30/2017      3152
3/31/2017      3152
2/28/2017      3153
1/31/2017      3153
12/31/2016     3153
11/30/2016     3153
10/31/2017     3153
9/30/2017      3153
8/31/2017      3153
7/31/2017      3153
6/30/2017      3153
5/31/2017      3940
4/30/2017      3940
3/31/2017      3940
2/28/2017      3940
1/31/2017      3940
```

I have the same set of data with 25 columns where every rows have different data set but the latest/last date has updated information. I want to pick the latest date rows of the employee.

Comment: could you provide an sample of your data and the expected result please ?

Comment: sum(x == value)

Comment: Date Worker ID

10/31/2017 3152
9/30/2017 3152
8/31/2017 3152
7/31/2017 3152
6/30/2017 3152
5/31/2017 3152
4/30/2017 3152
3/31/2017 3152
2/28/2017 3153
1/31/2017 3153
12/31/2016 3153
11/30/2016 3153
10/31/2017 3153
9/30/2017 3153
8/31/2017 3153
7/31/2017 3153
6/30/2017 3153
5/31/2017 3940
4/30/2017 3940
3/31/2017 3940
2/28/2017 3940
1/31/2017 3940















I have the same set of data with 25 columns where every rows have differernt data set but the latest/last date has updated infromation. I want to pick the latest date rows of the employee.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data in R code and what you when you want it to count something vs when you want it to not count it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data frame subsetting and `duplicated` function to imitate Excel's `COUNTIF`. Please see the code below:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
1L), .Label = c("1/31/2017", "10/31/2017", "11/30/2016", "12/31/2016", 
"2/28/2017", "3/31/2017", "4/30/2017", "5/31/2017", "6/30/2017", 
"7/31/2017", "8/31/2017", "9/30/2017"), class = "factor"), Worker_ID = c(3152L, 
3152L, 3152L, 3152L, 3152L, 3152L, 3152L, 3152L, 3153L, 3153L, 
3153L, 3153L, 3153L, 3153L, 3153L, 3153L, 3153L, 3940L, 3940L, 
3940L, 3940L, 3940L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))


df[!duplicated(df$Worker_ID), ]
```

Output:

```
         Date Worker_ID
1  10/31/2017      3152
9   2/28/2017      3153
18  5/31/2017      3940
```